# Maintaining State in a Memory Game Application: Cells Disappear when Flipping Cards

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm developing a memory game application in which I have a `Board` class responsible for representing the game board. However, I'm encountering an issue where the game board seems to lose all its cells when I attempt to flip a card by its ID.

simplified version of my `Board` class:

```cs
public class Board
{
    // ... (existing code)

    public bool FlipCard(int cardId)
    {
        var cellToFlip = cells.First(x => x.Id == cardId);
        if (cellToFlip != null) { cellToFlip.IsFlipped = true; return true; }
        return false;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I call the `FlipCard` method, the `_gameBoard` instance loses all its cells. I suspect this might be related to state not persisting between requests.

I've attempted to use session state to store the game board, but it didn't work as expected. The game board's cells were not maintained across requests, resulting in their disappearance.

Is there a recommended approach for persisting the game board's state between requests? How can I ensure that the game board retains its cells when flipping a card by ID?

Comment: *"I suspect it has something to do with the state not persisting between requests."* - That's exactly it.  This happens on every request: `_gameBoard = new Board();`  So every request results in an entirely new game.  You'd either need to maintain the game logic client-side without reloading the page or, if you want to maintain the logic server-side, persist the state of the game somewhere.  Session state, a database, etc.

Comment: i use ajax call to make a request to flip the card, so the page does not refresh. also when i make call via postman, i have the same problem.

Comment: Regardless of the use of AJAX, you're still keeping the game logic server-side.  You'd either want to move the logic client-side or you'd want to persist the state of the game somewhere server-side.  Such as session state or a database.  Currently the code shown never persists the state of the game anywhere.  Overall it sounds like you were simply expecting a web application to be stateful by default, and that expectation was incorrect.  Every HTTP request to this controller creates an entirely new instance of this controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decide how do you want to store the gaming progress. It can be done in multiple ways:

- Store session in a DB.
- Store gaming progress on client side
- else...

One of the approaches:

1. When a player request to "shuffle", you need to store board information with new game id somewhere.
2. When the player request to flip a card, he needs to provide game id and card id. Your back-end will find game session based on game id and execute requested changes based on your logic.

Your MVC does not stay alive all the time and does not behavies as a desktop application. Imagine that every your http call starts the MVC application from scratch.
Few examples of MVC application life cycle:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application

https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/asp-net-mvc-life-cycle/